# How to get the data of the ListView cell being tapped

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

our itemSource is from a json data and we deserialize it so we can put it in the Xaml listview and I cannot get the value of the cell being tapped.

This is my .cs

```
List<Debtor> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Debtor>>(filteredResult2);
//UPDATE LISTVIEW
CustListView.ItemsSource = ro;

CustListView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
       {
           await DisplayAlert("Selected", e.SelectedItem.ToString() + " was selected.", "OK");
           // await Navigation.PushAsync(new SalesHeaderPage());
       };
```

This is my .xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="CustListView">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <ViewCell >
       <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="8,0,8,0">
         <Label Text="{Binding debtor_name}" TextColor="#000" FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

       </StackLayout>
     </ViewCell>
   </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to cast it

something like

```
((Debtor)e.SelectedItem).debtor_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also add `(ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null`, because if you tap the same item again it won't work.So you need to clear the selected item.

`if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
var tappedItem = (Debtor)e.SelectedItem;
((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;`